# When performing a Core Data migration, how can I carry over old values from the source store from a different entity?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm performing a migration using Core Data's standard mapping model approach, and it seems to be working fine, except for one thing: I've moved an attribute from one entity to another, and I want to move the underlying value from the source store to that new entity as part of the migration.

This *should* be possible, but I'm having trouble figuring out which steps I need to take to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way is to subclass `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` and put your logic there. There you can import the class files of the other needed entity.

In Xcode you can set the "Expression" under "Attribute Mapping" as `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "yourMethodName", $source)`.